# primefaces close dialog on init don't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

Im'using Primefaces 5.0 and I tried to use PF Dialog Framework features, but with some problems.
I open a dialog using openDialog() method.
In the dialog bean I managed an init() method annotated with @PostConstruct.
In that method I read parameters and load a list of records (to bind with a dataTable).
All seems work fine... dialog opens, I choose a record , close with closeReturn and so on.

But I want that in init(), if a single record was found, I could close immediately the dialog.
So I call closeDialog(), passing my bean... but nothing happens... the dialog opens and I have to close it manually.
And this is frustrating...

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can use primefaces requestContext to close the dialog from your bean.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    recordList = loadListOfRecords();
    if ( recordList.size() == 1 ) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute('yourDialogWidgeVar.close()');
    }
}
```

This is just a possibility to close a dialog from Bean. I don't know if it fits to your demands.
Please post your code next time. It is hard to figure out your problem without it.