# Primefaces DialogFramework close on init

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have the same requirement as mentioned in "
[primefaces close dialog on init don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780435/primefaces-close-dialog-on-init-dont-work)" but the only answer is not a working solution, becaue in Dialog Framework i don't have a `widgetVar`.

My `@PostConstruct` method looks similar:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    Tree tree = initTree();
    if (tree.getChildCount() == 1) {
        // @todo close dialog if tree has only 1 child

        // this does not close the dialog
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(true);

        // this does not work, because there is no widgetVar
        //RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("yourDialogWidgetVar.close()");
    }
}
```

So, how can I close a DialogFramework xhtml page from its `@PostConstruct` method ?

I'm using Primefaces 6.0 on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

Comment: why you do not have a widgetVar

Comment: how to set widgetVar using dialog framework?!

Comment: did you see this post [Primefaces Dialog Framework - Open dialog - close it - open another dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897397/primefaces-dialog-framework-open-dialog-close-it-open-another-dialog)

Comment: Trying to close a dialog in a postConstruct is a weird (or at least very uncommon) way to solve a (for us unknown) requirement.

Comment: @Kukeltje: a better solution would be to create my tree of objects and show the dialog if there are more than 1 childrens in the tree. The point is, that i want to show the tree in the dialog but there is no way to pass the tree to the dialog bean using the params map in `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("", options, params)`. Is the only way to pass the tree via sessionMap?!